# Search distribution list in AD using email address in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to validate an email address within active directory. I stumbled upon a solution using System.DirectoryServices. Now I can validate a regular user, but this code doesn't work for a distribution group.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(filter: "(mail="+username+"*)");
SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
```

What am I doing wrong here? The distribution group I am trying to validate has a name like "My Group" and alias "mygroup". I am able to find the group if I do something like

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(filter: "cn=My Group");
```

The problem is, even if i do that, i can't find its email in its properties. And the bigger problem is, in my code, I won't have the cn for the group, just the email alias to search with.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `username`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen username is the useralias that's passed to this function. In my example, it would be "mygroup"

Answer (score 3):

In Active Directory, "mail" is a single-value attribute that holds the e-mail address. There's a multi-value attribute, proxyAddresses, that contain *all* of the entry's e-mail addresses and it's this value that is actually used by Exchange. While most users have a single e-mail address that is present in both mail and proxyAddresses, that is not always the case. Validating e-mail addresses against mail can yield false failures. As an example, where I work, someone who changes their name retains their old e-mail address in proxyAddresses for 90 days to allow them to communicate their new address to contacts. It's still a valid address for the individual, but *just* looking in mail will say the address is invalid.

Values in proxyAddresses are prefixed with the transport (generally "smtp", as a preponderance of mail flow is SMTP-based ... although it's possible some other transport is used -- search for a known record and return proxyAddresses to see what's in use in *your* directory).

Assuming SMTP is the transport, the filter to find an account by one of its proxyAddresses values is:

```
(&(proxyAddresses=smtp:me@example.com))
```

Here's a quick sample console app I've used that successfully finds both security and distribution groups in my domain.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ADServer.example.com","lisa@example.com","!P@ssw0rdG03sH3r3!", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
            {
                PageSize = int.MaxValue,
                //                Filter = "(&(mail=LJRTestDistroGroup@example.com))"
                                Filter = "(&(proxyAddresses=smtp:LJRTestSecurityGroup@example.com))"
            };

            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses");
            searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

            SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();

            List<string> names = new List<string>();

            foreach (SearchResult r in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(r.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(r.Properties["proxyAddresses"][0].ToString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @LisaJ, but this format is still not working for me. It works for an individual user, but not for a group. I can see the proxy email addresses for that group in the outlook app, and I'm using one of those addresses exactly as it is, (even with capitalization) to filter. 

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(filter: "(&(proxyAddresses=SMTP:mygroup@example.com))");

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does DirectorySearcher only work for individual users? I tried searching for couple of other groups as well, but no result.

Comment: No, I've used DirectorySearcher for groups in the past. I just wrote a quick console app that searches for groups by both mail and proxyAddresses (added above). Are you certain the group's e-mail address matches the username (i.e. the address *is* mygroup@example.com)?

Comment: Yes, I have used that email address multiple times and I even see it in the outlook app when I open the group in address book. My problem is, I can find that group using "name" filter but I still don't see the proxyaddresses or mail properties in it; even if I add them to searcher's PropertiesToLoad. Are these properties just hidden or require some special permission to view them? I also looped through ALL the groups we have and saw the properties loading for some of them and not for others!

Comment: The *default* in AD is that authenticated users can read everything, but that's something admins tweak on occasion. In a sandbox AD, I can create a new account that is just a member of 'domain users' and read proxyAddresses and mail for mail-enabled groups. Are you using your account to bind to Active Directory or a system account? The permissions are the same from Outlook to LDAP, so if you can see it one place you can see it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted IT and turns out that the group I was searching for is not in AD, but in office 365! The groups that I can find with email addresses exist in AD. I guess I need to look into Office 365 APIs now.

That still doesn't explain to me why I was able to find the group using its name!

The logic I originally had for searching a group was right, though it was using mail as a filter and clearly, proxyaddrresses is more accurate, so I'm marking @LisaJ's response as answer.